# I want to generate continuously number by 2 column and batch wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number, rownum

I want to generate continuously number with the combination of 2 columns and in batch size of 5. Anybody can help to solve this?

[image: This is my input and desired output is given:]

Comment: You have a Typo.  Rank is `30` on the left and `20` on the right, for the third from last row of `Paras`.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for correction. I am going to update it.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An adoption of @GordonLinoff's answer...

```
SELECT
    name,
    rank, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name DESC, Rank, ((seqnum - 1) / 5))  AS rno   
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, rank ORDER BY (SELECT null))   AS seqnum
    FROM
        yourTable
)
    sequenced
ORDER BY
    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your answer is totally correct. Thanks again it will helps me a lot.

Can you please correct your answer due to some little syntax error like " ROW_NUMBER() OVER " instead of " ROW_NUMBER() AS "

Comment: @gordonLinoff - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select name, rank, 
       ((seqnum - 1) / 5) + 1 as rno
from (select t.*,
              row_number() as (partition by name, rank order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Looking at the OPs example, there should be no partitioning, just ordering.  *(The `Rno` never resets to 1)*. I think this would need at least two levels of analytic functions, such as applying `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name DESC, Rank, ((seqnum - 1) / 5))` in the outer query?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my desired output is different from which you answered. Please see our Input and their corresponding output in deeply.  If any name has been changed then also Rno should be increase from that max Rno. It have not to start from 1.